# How to create object of .net library using 64 bit excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm getting an error 429: ActiveX component can't create object, when referencing a Visual Studio 2008 C# library from 64 bit Excel 2010. 
Note: The create object method works just fine on 32 bit Excel 2010.

I am using below call to create object:

```
Set commonLib = CreateObject("AutoLib.Common")
```

Does anyone has any idea about this.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities spring to mind:

1) Have you checked the build configuration of the C# library - is it set to build for x86 (i.e. 32 bit)? If so, try changing that to 'Any Configuration' or 'x64'.

2) Is the library where Excel 64-bit expects it be? I have seen problems where people have hard coded paths (e.g. C:\Program Files(x86)) or registry keys, which don't behave as well as they hoped when switching to 64-bit!

Comment: Thanks for pointers Chris. I have tried addressing point#1 but that does not resolve the issue and point # 2 is already taken care of but still I am facing same issues  :-(

Comment: I could be able to create an object of Visual Studio 2008 C# library from 64 bit Excel 2010 by setting build to x86 option but I am unable to create objects of libraries which are developed in VB6. Any ideas?